# Video texture Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with getting a video texture to show up in unity 5.2 personal edition. I have applied a material with unlit shader and assigned it as a video texture. I also call the specific video texture through a script attached to the object with the video texture.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

    public class CallMovie : MonoBehaviour {
        public MovieTexture myMovie;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            Debug.Log ("start intro");
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = myMovie;// get movie
            myMovie.Play ();// shall play movie

        }
        void Update(){
            myMovie.loop =true;
        }
    }
```

When I hit the play button in unity the video texture stays black and nothing happens om screen although the program says it ran the video when checked with debug log.

Comment: In the log does "start intro" show up?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant post questions in comment on your initial the following is an attempt to answer with what I know.

In your first statement after the debug call you are setting the maintexture component of the instanced material to myMovie, depending on shader this may or may not work as 'mainTexture' may not be referencing the texture you expect.

You can insure you hit the desired texture using the following method

```
        //Note the diffrence between a material instance and the shared material
        //... dont forget to clean up instances if you make them which hapens when you call .material
        Material instancedMaterial = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        Material sharedMaterial = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;

        //_MainTex is the name of the main texture for most stock shaders ... but not all
        //You can select the shader by clicking the gear in the inspector of the material
        //this will display the shader in the inspector where you can see its properties by name
        instancedMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", movie);
```

The following code is from a working class object I use to set a Unity UI object RawImage to render a movie. From what I see in your example you have the movie part correct I suspect your issue is with the shader parameter.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RawImageMovePlayer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.RawImage imageSource;

    public bool play;
    public bool isLoop = true;

    public MovieTexture movie;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        movie = (MovieTexture)imageSource.texture;
        movie.loop = isLoop;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (!movie.isPlaying && play)
            movie.Play();
    }

    public void ChangeMovie(MovieTexture movie)
    {
        imageSource.texture = movie;

        this.movie = (MovieTexture)imageSource.texture;
        this.movie.loop = isLoop;
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        if (movie != null && movie.isPlaying)
            movie.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks really much for your answer, I shall test this.